# Keras model doesn't work with a larger dataset

Tags: python, keras, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm just getting started with Keras and with Deep learning, so the answer to my question could be obvious to some, but for me it isn't.

I made a model to colorize some black and white photos following the article on Floydhub (where I'm training it) and it works just fine when I train it with similar pictures (such as human faces) but as soon as I use a larger dataset as an input with different pictures, the loss just remains stable and doesn't get better.

I've tried different learning rates and optimizers but just cannot get a good result.

What could I change to get a better result?

This is the code  (thanks to Emil Wallner for the article on Floydhub)

```
# Get images
X = []
for filename in os.listdir('/data/images/Train/'):
    X.append(img_to_array(load_img('/data/images/Train/'+filename)))
X = np.array(X, dtype=float)
Xtrain = 1.0/255*X

#Load weights
inception = InceptionResNetV2(weights=None, include_top=True)
inception.load_weights('/data/inception_resnet_v2_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5')
inception.graph = tf.get_default_graph()

embed_input = Input(shape=(1000,))

#Encoder
encoder_input = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1,))
encoder_output = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(encoder_input)
encoder_output = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_output)

#Fusion
fusion_output = RepeatVector(32 * 32)(embed_input) 
fusion_output = Reshape(([32, 32, 1000]))(fusion_output)
fusion_output = concatenate([encoder_output, fusion_output], axis=3) 
fusion_output = Conv2D(256, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same')(fusion_output) 

#Decoder
decoder_output = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(fusion_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = Conv2D(2, (3, 3), activation='tanh', padding='same')(decoder_output)
decoder_output = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder_output)

model = Model(inputs=[encoder_input, embed_input], outputs=decoder_output)

#Create embedding
def create_inception_embedding(grayscaled_rgb):
    grayscaled_rgb_resized = []
    for i in grayscaled_rgb:
        i = resize(i, (299, 299, 3), mode='constant')
        grayscaled_rgb_resized.append(i)
    grayscaled_rgb_resized = np.array(grayscaled_rgb_resized)
    grayscaled_rgb_resized = preprocess_input(grayscaled_rgb_resized)
    with inception.graph.as_default():
        embed = inception.predict(grayscaled_rgb_resized)
    return embed

# Image transformer
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        shear_range=0.4,
        zoom_range=0.4,
        rotation_range=40,
        horizontal_flip=True)

#Generate training data
batch_size = 20

def image_a_b_gen(batch_size):
    for batch in datagen.flow(Xtrain, batch_size=batch_size):
        grayscaled_rgb = gray2rgb(rgb2gray(batch))
        embed = create_inception_embedding(grayscaled_rgb)
        lab_batch = rgb2lab(batch)
        X_batch = lab_batch[:,:,:,0]
        X_batch = X_batch.reshape(X_batch.shape+(1,))
        Y_batch = lab_batch[:,:,:,1:] / 128
        yield ([X_batch, create_inception_embedding(grayscaled_rgb)], Y_batch)

#Train model      
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="/output")
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit_generator(image_a_b_gen(batch_size), callbacks=[tensorboard], epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch=20)

#Make a prediction on the unseen images
color_me = []
for filename in os.listdir('../Test/'):
    color_me.append(img_to_array(load_img('../Test/'+filename)))
color_me = np.array(color_me, dtype=float)
color_me = 1.0/255*color_me
color_me = gray2rgb(rgb2gray(color_me))
color_me_embed = create_inception_embedding(color_me)
color_me = rgb2lab(color_me)[:,:,:,0]
color_me = color_me.reshape(color_me.shape+(1,))


# Test model
output = model.predict([color_me, color_me_embed])
output = output * 128

# Output colorizations
for i in range(len(output)):
    cur = np.zeros((256, 256, 3))
    cur[:,:,0] = color_me[i][:,:,0]
    cur[:,:,1:] = output[i]
    imsave("result/img_"+str(i)+".png", lab2rgb(cur))
```

Comment: And what is your code?

Comment: How does your model look like?

Comment: Added it, sorry

Comment: If the code still runs, this probably isn't a good question for SO.  You can't provide us with the new dataset, so we can't test it.  It's going to be hard to provide a [mcve], the gold standard for a good SO question.